# Terminating unicode null character

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have an array of wchar_t. I need to add a unicode null character at a specific position in the array.

```
wchar_t var1[100];

var1[79] = '\u0000';
```

I tried the above but get the following compilation error.

```
error C3850: '\u0000': a universal-character-name specifies an invalid character
```

How do I add a unicode null character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language doesn't allow you to use universal character names for characters that you can easily write without using a UCN.  That's why `'\u0000'` isn't permitted.  (I'm not quite sure what the rationale for that rule is.)

Since `var1` is an array of `wchar_t`, `L'\0'` is the most straightforward thing to use.

But since `char`, `wchar_t`, and `int` are all integral types, and since values of any integral type can be assigned to an object of another integral type (as long as the value is in range of the target type), any of the following will work:

```
var1[79] = L'\0'; // best
var1[79] = '\0';  // char value converted to wchar_t
var1[79] = 0;     // int value converted to wchar_t
```

Comment: Yep, C++03 §2.2/2 says "If the hexadecimal value for a universal character name is less than 0x20 or in the range 0x7F-0x9F (inclusive), or if the universal character name designates a character in the basic source character set, then the program is illformed."

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use

```
var1[79] = L'\0'
```

Answer (score 4):

I have programmed some simple window applications using raw api32 and my best guess is to use L'\0'.

Answer (score 3):

Integer zero will also do:

```
var1[79] = 0;
```

Comment: I always feel like assigning numbers to characters is a bad idea, and prefer `'\0'`.